# How do I get the minimization of this boolean expression?

Tags: boolean-logic

a'b'c + a'bc' + ab'c' + ab'c + abc'+ abc

```
The answer is a + b'c +bc'
```

But I get this...

```
a'(b'c+bc) + ab'(c'+c) + ab(c'+c) 
    "        ab'+ ab
    "        a(b'+b)
a'(b'c+bc')+ a
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about boolean logic / [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

The solution can be visually verified using a Karnaugh Veitch map:

[image]